# why rsync overall transfer rate larger than bwlimit?

Tags: rsync

I ran some backup tasks using rsync with bwlimit 10M/s(i.e. --bwlimit=10000) every day, and I calculated task size,start time and end time for the tasks. I found  that for some tasks the  overall transfer rate  is mucher larger than bwlimit. Here is the exmaple,
task size 37416328KB
start time 2016-07-29 06:06:39
end time 2016-07-29 06:26:42
so the overall transfer rate = 37416328/1024/1203=30.37M/s

Comment: How did you calculate the task size? Did you enable compression? What does `--stats` say?

Comment: Oh ,yes.I calculated it by the original size,but in fact it is compressed during transmission.